# react-checkbox-tree icons not shown properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, tree

I am trying to implement filtering of items which will be shown on a map. Items have a field, lets call it `itemType`. `itemType` could have one of many values. Each value belongs to one of couple of categories. In order to allow all item types from single category to be selected/deselected by checking particular category, I decided to use `react-checkbox-tree`.

```
Category1
    ItemType1
    ItemType2
    ...
Category2
    ItemType3
    ItemType4
    ...
...
```

I found simple example demonstrating `react-checkbox-tree` [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-checkbox-tree-3hcvdb).
Example works seamlessly.
[image: Example]

But when I try the code in my application the icons for items are not shown properly.
It looks like on image below:
[image: MyTry]

The callback which I passed to `onCheck` hook, is called when item is checked/unchecked, and I can see the the checked items are added to the array of checked items. I even see that the weird icon is changed (between `F096` and `F046`) when item is checked/unchecked.

Does anyone know how can make icons appear as on example on **stackblitz**?

It is worth noting that I am C++ developer, and this is my first time writing reactjs app, so I would appreciate answer as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made icons work by using **react-icons** package.

```
import {
    MdCheckBox,
    MdCheckBoxOutlineBlank,
    MdChevronRight,
    MdKeyboardArrowDown,
    MdAddBox,
    MdIndeterminateCheckBox,
    MdFolder,
    MdFolderOpen,
    MdInsertDriveFile
} from "react-icons/md";
...

function MyComponent() {
    ...
    const nodes = ...
    const icons = {
        check: <MdCheckBox className="rct-icon-check" />,
        uncheck: <MdCheckBoxOutlineBlank className=" rct-icon-uncheck" />,
        halfCheck: <MdIndeterminateCheckBox className=" rct-icon-half-check" />,
        expandClose:<MdChevronRight className=" rct-icon-expand-close" />,
        expandOpen:<MdKeyboardArrowDown className=" rct-icon-expand-open" />,
        expandAll: <MdAddBox className=" rct-icon-expand-all" />,
        collapseAll: <MdIndeterminateCheckBox className=" rct-icon-collapse-all" />,
        parentClose: <MdFolder className=" rct-icon-parent-close" />,
        parentOpen: <MdFolderOpen className=" rct-icon-parent-open" />,
        leaf: <MdInsertDriveFile className=" rct-icon-leaf-close" />
    };
    ...

    return (
        <CheckboxTree
        icons={icons}
        nodes={nodes}
        ...
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The icons in the example rely on special unicode characters from the Font `Font Awesome 5 Free` (fallback to `FontAwesome` )
The icons in your case are the fallback from the browser, when a font does not contain the specified unicode character.

Either you miss a font-family definition (like below), or you do not server the font.

```css
font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free", "FontAwesome", sans-serif;
```

https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/ shows the different methods to include the fonts to your web page.

Comment: I tried to add font-family definition to CSS selector for the **checkboxtree** but it didn't work. I guess, I still don't understand how this works. However, I made icons work by using **react-icons** package.